# Java multithreads mix text in not working output file-lock

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Java application in which I start 100 threads. The threads, after parsing xml files and extracting some text from them, open a file to write the extracted text. However, it seems that they mix the results (the output file is not in the supposed order).
I used `Lock` but it did not solve the problem. Can anyone help?

```
Main.java


public class Main {




   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {



  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Michael\\outfilenames0.txt");

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

  String strLine;


  int j=0;

  while (((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) && (j<100))

  {
      int activethreads=Thread.activeCount();


      SimpleThread t=new SimpleThread(strLine);
       t.start();

       if (activethreads>100)
           SimpleThread.sleep(250);
       if (j==99)
       {j=-1;}

       //System.out.println(t.getName());
       j++;


    }

  }

}




class SimpleThread extends Thread {


    private String str;


    public SimpleThread(String str) {
        this.str=str;

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {
            Lock l=new ReentrantLock();
            if (l.tryLock()){
                try {
                SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

           // create SAX-parser...
                SAXParser parser=factory.newSAXParser();

            SaxHandler handler = new SaxHandler();
            parser.parse(str, handler);
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SimpleThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }finally {l.unlock();}

            } else Thread.currentThread().sleep(10);


        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(SimpleThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } catch (SAXException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(SimpleThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(SimpleThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 

    }

}






  class SaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {

       private boolean invention_title = false;
       private boolean invention_title_lang = false;

       private boolean abstr = false;
       private boolean abstr_lang = false;

       private boolean descr = false;
       private boolean description_lang = false;

       private String doc="";
       private String ucid;

       @Override
       public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
               String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {

           if (qName.equals("patent-document")) {

               ucid = attrs.getValue("ucid");
               doc= ("<DOC>\n<DOCNO> " + ucid  +"</DOCNO> \n<TEXT>" );
                          }

           if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("invention-title")) {
                       invention_title = true;
                       String title_language = attrs.getValue("lang");
                       if (title_language.equals("EN"))
                       {
                           invention_title_lang = true;
                           doc=doc+"<TITLE>"+"\n";
                                          }
                                  }

           if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("abstract")) {
                       abstr = true;
                       String abst_language = attrs.getValue("lang");
                       if (abst_language.equals("EN"))  {abstr_lang = true;
                       doc=doc+"<ABSTRACT>"+"\n" ;
                                        }
                       }


           if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                       descr = true;
                       String des_language = attrs.getValue("lang");
                       if (des_language.equals("EN"))  {description_lang = true;
                       doc=doc+"<DESCRIPTION>"+"\n";
                                         }
                                }}


@Override 


public void endElement (String uri, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException
{
   if((qName.equals("abstract"))&& (abstr_lang)){
       abstr_lang = false;
       doc=doc+"</ABSTRACT>"+"\n";
       }

    if((qName.equals("invention-title"))&&(invention_title_lang)){
       invention_title_lang = false;
       doc=doc+"</TITLE>"+"\n";
      }

    if((qName.equals("description"))&&(description_lang)){
       description_lang = false;
       doc=doc+"</DESCRIPTION>"+"\n";
       }

      if(qName.equals("patent-document")){
       doc=doc+"</TEXT>"+"\n"+"</DOC>"+"\n";
       //System.out.println("</DOC>");
          //Lock l=new ReentrantLock();

         // if (l.tryLock())
            //try {


              FileWrite fileWrite = new FileWrite();
                try {
                    fileWrite.FileWrite(ucid, doc);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SaxHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
           // }finally {l.unlock();}
                 //   catch (IOException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(SaxHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          //  }

    }

   }

       @Override
       public  void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
throws SAXException {


               if ( invention_title_lang) {
                      doc=doc+ (new String(ch, start, length))+"\n";                  
               }

                if ( abstr_lang) {
                    doc=doc+ (new String(ch, start, length));

               }

               if ( description_lang) {
                   doc=doc+ (new String(ch, start, length));
                        }
            }
}




class FileWrite
{

 public synchronized void FileWrite(String ucid, String doc) throws IOException

 {
     Thread t=Thread.currentThread();
try{



    FileWriter fstreamout = new FileWriter("EP-022",true);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstreamout);
    out.write(doc);
    out.close();

   if (t.isAlive())
   {
   t.stop();}
     }
catch (Exception e)
{
System.err.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
     }
}




}
```

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
Lock l=new ReentrantLock();
```

in `SimpleThread.run()` will create a new lock for each instance of `SimpleThread` which is pointless and the only synchronization between all threads will be the `FileWrite()` method. If you want to have a lock shared by all instances of `SimpleThread` then add a `static Lock` member variable:

```
static Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
```

However, doing so will mean the threads will execute sequentially, which makes it pretty pointless having threads at all.

An alternative would be for `SimpleThread` to parse its XML file (no requirement for a lock) and cache the results in memory (in an `ArrayList<String>()` that would store the lines to be written to a file). The `main()` thread would wait for all `SimpleThread` instances to complete and then write the results of each to the file. This would permit the parsing of the XML to be concurrent and ensure an ordered output file.

Comment: +1. I agree with you. I would say also that the string "ucid", as parameter of synchronized constructor of FileWrite class, is not used, and the use of the deprecated stop() Thread method is not recommended, because it's better to invoke t.interrupt().

Answer (score 0):

You may try 'synchronized', this at least ensures at a time one of your threads are running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 100 Threads, then I would suggest

> 1. Use a Thread pool - things can get so much easier with them
> 2. 100 Threads is A LOT of threads, why did you choose so many? It's not like having more Threads means doing the work faster(not always at least). The CPU will have to do a lot of work to play with them correctly and I don't think you are using this app on a multi-core architecture. (>4 for example)  Try to scale your app and run a few tests to see if you get any improvement from 5-10 Threads to 100.

**EDIT** You are not running ALL 100 Threads at a time, I still think that creating a potentially 100 simultaneous threads is not a good option.

> 1. Do not extend Thread, but create an implementation for Runnable
> 2. Of course they will mix results, it does not matter that you start Threads one after the other, the order in which they run is always un-predictable.
> 3. To make them do your work correctly you could synchronize them on the SAME lock, but then what is the purpose of having 100 Threads if they will execute one after another? Second Thread will wait for the First, Third will wait for Second and so on... in this case you could get rid of the Threads and do it with just one. 
>      OR you could implement Callable instead of Runnable and pass to each Thread the currect line number, when the Thread is done, it will return the result with the line number it was dealing with. Put that result in PriorityBlockingQueue and sort them according to the line number (using a Comparator), then just get them and output the result.

There are people here who (I hope) will suggest probably more (and I really hope better) solutions also ;)

Cheers, Eugene.